# How to have an input box pop up in VBA only if certain criteria is met?

Tags: vba, if-statement, inputbox

I'm attempting to set up an input box that will come up if the value in a certain cell (I4) is greater than 0.  I then want to make it so that if nothing is entered in the cell it will prompt the user to enter information.  If the user presses cancel, then the macro should stop.

```
Sub testing123()

Re_Enter_FileImport:
FileImport = InputBox("File Not Yet Imported, Please Provide Reasoning")

If Range("I4") <> 0 Then
    Answer = FileImport

 'Code if user pressed cancel

If StrPtr(FileImport) = 0 Then
    Exit Sub

ElseIf FileImport = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please Provide Reasoning"
    GoTo Re_Enter_FileImport:
Else
End If

End Sub
```

When I try this code, the Input Box pops up no matter if the info in cell I4 is 0 or not.  Also, how do I define where the user's answer will be entered?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this with a Do While Loop that will keep going until the user inputs a value or presses cancel. Additionally, you can then place their answer where you need it with the `.Value` property.

```
Sub testing123()

Dim FileImport As String
Dim AnsBool As Boolean

AnsBool = True

If Range("A4") > 0 Then

    FileImport = InputBox("File Not Yet Imported, Please Provide Reasoning")

    Do While AnsBool
        If StrPtr(FileImport) = 0 Then Exit Sub
        If FileImport <> "" Then Exit Do
        MsgBox "Please Provide Reasoning"
        FileImport = InputBox("File Not Yet Imported, Please Provide Reasoning")
    Loop
End If

'You can change this to the range needed
Range("A1").Value = FileImport
End Sub
```